# Rails: How to query a record using each_with_index while seeding a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a posts table with 100 blank posts which I plan to seed with content from a post_content.csv file. The csv has the HTML content of each post in each row.

#### seeds.rb

```
File.open("post_content.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |line, index|
    content = line.chomp
    n = index + 1
    @post = Post.find_by_id(n)
    @post.update(content: content)
  end
end
```

However, when I seed the content, I get an error:

```
undefined method 'update' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I correctly find each post based on the index number?

Comment: Did you check the indexes (n) are taking the proper values? e.g: if index equals 1, n equals 2, is there a Post with id 2?

Comment: Are you sure you have Posts with indexes 1 to 100?. Anyway, you should always check if find_by really found the record. If not found, it returns nil.

Comment: The indexes exist and the 2 answers below solved it, but I don't know why there should be a conditional just to make it work: (if @post) and (unless @post.nil?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the value **based on index**, you can use **offset** as in below code :

```
File.open("post_content.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |line, index|  
    @post = Post.offset(index).first
    @post.update(content: line.chomp) if @post.present?
  end
end
```

`Offset` is used to skip records.
Reference:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset

Answer (score 0):

There are some Post ID not available in database so your script crash. Run below script to know which ID not available.

```
File.open("post_content.csv", "r") do |f|
  f.each_with_index do |line, index|
    content = line.chomp
    n = index + 1
    @post = Post.find_by_id(n)
    if @post
      @post.update(content: content)
      next
    puts "The Post with id #{n} was not found."
  end
end
```